# How to remove individual sources from auto-complete's ac-sources in a specific major-mode

Tags: hooks, auto-complete-mode

`auto-complete` automatically adds a number of sources to `ac-sources`:

```el
(ac-source-features ac-source-functions ac-source-variables ac-source-symbols)
```

And I set up `auto-complete` default `ac-sources` like this:

```el
(ac-source-yasnippet ac-source-abbrev ac-source-filename ac-source-files-in-current-dir 
 ac-source-capf ac-source-gtags ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers)
```

But I found that some sources listed in `ac-sources` complete the same thing. For example, I get the following completions for `(setq)`:

- `ac-source-functions` shows: `setq f`
- `ac-source-symbols` shows: `setq s`
- `ac-source-capf` shows: `setq s`
- `ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers` shows: `setq`

I want to disable the following sources only in `emacs-lisp-mode`: 
`ac-source-symbols`, `ac-source-capf`.

How can I do this?

(If you know of any other way to solve my problem, please leave a comment. Thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a similar solution:

```el
(defun ac-source-remove (source-removed-list)
  "Remove some ac-source from ac-sources.

Example:
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (ac-source-remove '(ac-source-capf ac-source-symbols))))"
  (interactive)
  ;; Use `remq' instead of `delq' which will remove element in global `ac-sources' too.
  (mapc (lambda (x) (setq-local ac-sources (remq x ac-sources)))
        source-removed-list))

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook
          (lambda () (ac-source-remove '(ac-source-capf ac-source-symbols))))
```

Comment: You should avoid using anonymous functions (`lambda`) when adding functionality to mode hooks. It makes values of hook variables harder to read, and you can't use `remove-hook` to remove functionality later on. Instead, you should define a function that implements the desired behavior and add that to the mode hook.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that deletes `ac-source-symbols` and `ac-source-capf` from `ac-sources`:

```el
(defun ac-remove-sources ()
  (setq ac-sources (delete 'ac-source-capf ac-sources))
  (setq ac-sources (delete 'ac-source-symbols ac-sources)))
```

You can tell Emacs to run this function for `emacs-lisp-mode` buffers by adding it to `emacs-lisp-mode-hook` like so:

```el
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'ac-remove-sources t)
```

Note that in order to make sure that it overrides the default behavior, you'll need to put this code *after* the code that loads the default customizations for `auto-complete` in your init-file.

Comment: right, I need to put this behind default initialize, I think that's why my config not working.